# WorkLight Server Configuration Tool - Deployment Error

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

When I try to create a runtime environment using WorkLight Server configuration tool (for WorkLight 6.2), I get the following error.

```
[installworklightadmin] Copying C:\dev\MYSQL\Connector J 5.1.31\mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin.jar to C:\IBM\WebSphere\Liberty\usr\shared\resources\wladmin\mysql\mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin.jar
[installworklightadmin] Copying C:\IBM\WebSphere\Liberty\usr\servers\worklightServer\server.xml to C:\IBM\WebSphere\Liberty\usr\servers\worklightServer\server.xml.bak3

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Documents\IBM Worklight Server Data\Server Configuration Tool\Configuration_Hello\Hello.xml:74: java.io.IOException: Failed to set restrictive permissions on file C:\IBM\WebSphere\Liberty\usr\servers\worklightServer\server.xml.bak3
    at com.ibm.worklight.config.util.osenv.FileProtector.protectConfidentialFile(FileProtector.java:98)
    at com.ibm.worklight.config.ant.appserver.AppServerTask.copyConfidentialFile(AppServerTask.java:4568)
```

I am using Windows 7 OS, WorkLight 6.2, with Libery Profile 8.5 & MySQL 5.6

Any help in resolving this issue is appreciated.

Regards,
Francis.

Comment: I don't know what's causing this, but you might check a few things: 1) Java version 6 or higher (http://www-969.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/prereqsForProduct?deliverableId=968A9CE03A2E11E396F9FC10E99BE807)  2) Details on Server Config tool and permissions (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/deploy/c_using_server_config_tool.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what happens in case it can help you resolve the situation.
The Worklight Server Configuration tool makes a backup for server.xml before modifying it. To protect the data in this backup, it attemps to restrict the access to the file to only the Windows user that did run the Server Configuration Tool. That operation fails - maybe because of security configuration in the Liberty server directory (or parent directory) that prevent this.

Workaround suggested:

- Run the Server Configuration Tool as Administrator it he Liberty usr directory is under Program Files
- Or change the usr directory of liberty so that the servers are created in a directory where you have full read/write access -- See http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/twlp_admin_customvars.html?lang=en VARIABLE WLP_USER_DIR

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. But I could resolve it by running the 'Server Configuration Tool' in the admin mode!!